# what does hard copy subscription mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I want to know what does "hard copy subscription" mean ?

full sentence :
where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription).

reference : [paid and free apps](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html)

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hard copy (of a magazine, for instance) is a paper version, versus a digital version.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so it's mean real product , right ?

Comment: @adamkaplan If that is your understanding of *reality* - yes.

Comment: the real product is a product which I can touch with my hand, like newspaper , not like pdf files or word files which are opened via other devices.

Comment: @adamkaplan - I understand the point you are making. But when you are talking about a book or a magazine, we should be more concerned about the content and not the medium. A PDF will have the same content as a printed one. Isn't it?

Comment: When _hard copy_ is used as a modifier, it is usually rendered as _hardcopy_.

Comment: I think this answer would be clearer if it said  *...versus a digital version, i.e. "soft" copy*.